# Insert-select mistake with 'WITH' keyword

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working in a app that converts to xml certain tables of my database (SqlServer 2008) and it saves them in other table.
The instruction that converts the table to xml is this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as inf)
 SELECT field1 as [inf:field1],field2 as [inf:field2] FROM dbo.table FOR XML PATH('inf:table_path'), ELEMENTS, ROOT('inf:table_root')
```

This works correctly.
But when I tried to do the insert in the database of this way:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tabla_XML (XMLFile) values(WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as inf)
SELECT field1 as [inf:field1],field2 as [inf:field2] FROM dbo.table FOR XML PATH('inf:table_path'), ELEMENTS, ROOT('inf:table_root'))
```

I get this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I tried to put the semicolon (;) before the with statement, but it doesn't work neither.

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance.
Regards!

Comment: You are not using `XMLNAMESPACES` anywhere in the statement.  The `with` seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as inf)
INSERT INTO dbo.tabla_XML (XMLFile) values((
SELECT field1 as [inf:field1],field2 as [inf:field2] FROM dbo.table FOR XML PATH('inf:table_path'), ELEMENTS, ROOT('inf:table_root')))
```

Comment: Yes, I needed to put with xmlnamespaces at the beginning of the sentence. Thanks a lot